# Linking multiple objects to HttpEntity

Tags: java, request, resttemplate, httpentity

My rest api uses POST request with 2 object parameters: custom type and long

[image]

I can link one parameter to body like this:

```
private void createCaseParticipant(long caseId, CaseParticipantDTO caseParticipantDTO)
    {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NAME, BASIC_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_PREFIX + cmsRestApiCreds);

        HttpEntity<CaseParticipantDTO> postRequest = new HttpEntity<CaseParticipantDTO>(caseParticipantDTO, headers);
    }
```

How can I add second parameter to my request? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply add it to the HttpHeadersobjects something like this :

```html
private void createCaseParticipant(long caseId, CaseParticipantDTO caseParticipantDTO)
    {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NAME, BASIC_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_PREFIX + cmsRestApiCreds);
        headers.add("caseId",caseId.toString());
        headers.add("caseParticipantDTO", caseParticipantDTO.toString());
        HttpEntity<CaseParticipantDTO> postRequest = new HttpEntity<CaseParticipantDTO>(caseParticipantDTO, headers);
    }
```